# Umbraco Package Action: Give all Users access to custom section

Tags: umbraco7

Hi I am building a new package and I want to give all users access to the new section automatically when the package is being installed.

I have found the GrantPermissionForApp class action in the "PackageActionsContrib" project, but the injected SQL is targeting tables that now do not exist.

Umbraco now sets section permissions on group Membership not at the user level, hence the SQL table "umbracoUser2app" doesn't exist.

Has anyone modded the GrantPermissionForApp class to account to the Umbraco changes or could advise what tables I need to mod in SQL?

Many thanks.

Comment: Which version of Umbraco are you using? I just checked version 7.5.8 and the umbracoUser2app table does exist in that version

Comment: Well I am using Umbraco 7.7.7, but I checked also 7.8.1 doesn't have it. Assigning sections used to be by user, butnow... its by group.

Comment: Hold on...there is a umbracoUserGroup2App table, the contents list the sections against a userGroupId.

Comment: The old table looks exactly like the new table.It looks like it maps the group ID to the section. I;ll have a crack at the GrantPermissionForApp class for the new table.